# Modifying a gulp build process using useref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-useref

I started using [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) to scaffold and build my angular/sass projects. When I run `gulp build` it uses `gulp-useref` to create optimised versions of the javascript and css files. This is the task responsible...

```
gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html');
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
  var assets;

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.csso())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyHtml({
      empty: true,
      spare: true,
      quotes: true,
      conditionals: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
});
```

I'd like to modify this to produce both minimized and non-minimized versions of the javascript and css files. I'd also like the javascript and css files to be called the name-version of the project. The name is specified in the `index.html` file where you can see `styles/app.css`...

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Although I could hard-code a name here I was wondering if `gulp` can read the name of the project here from the package? For instance, in `grunt` you can write...

```
<!-- build:js scripts/combined.<%= grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').version %>.concat.min.js -->
<!-- You can put comments in here too -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/that.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Does anyone know if you can do something similar in `grunt`? I can't find any examples of this?